# Why will MySQL correctly save "&#153;" in a varchar field, but save it as "â„¢" in a text field?

Tags: mysql

The PHP code used to process both strings from a $_POST input to the database save is identical.  The only preparation done before the save is:

```
trim(stripslashes($string))
```

FYI - the inputs are from a secured admin site, not a user interface, so protecting against code injection and similar nonsense is not a big issue.  Getting the right data saved is.
 Server uses PHP 5.4 and MySQL 5.5

Any ideas?

Comment: What code are you using to insert in the database?  Seeing `stripslashes` is never a good sign since that method is not really appropriate for database escaping.

Comment: mysql does NOT do html encoding. if you get the raw character in the db, then it's something in your code that's doing the encoded->raw translation.

Comment: " the inputs are from a secured admin site" you still want to protect against code injection for a number of reasons, including disgruntled employees/users, and passwords getting hacked. Just my 2 cents Canadian.

Comment: @ajacian81 Exactly. "Protecting against code injection" is always an issue. If you don't at least follow the basic best practices you will get burned.

Answer (score 0):

Some times special characters violence the query. so use real_escape_string function. for ex-

```
    <?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$mysqli->query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myCity LIKE City");

$city = "'s Hertogenbosch";

/* this query will fail, cause we didn't escape $city */
if (!$mysqli->query("INSERT into myCity (Name) VALUES ('$city')")) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", $mysqli->sqlstate);
}

$city = $mysqli->real_escape_string($city);

/* this query with escaped $city will work */
if ($mysqli->query("INSERT into myCity (Name) VALUES ('$city')")) {
    printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $mysqli->affected_rows);
}

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: Please try and avoid using the out of date `mysql_query` functions in answers. It's 2015. It's time to stop using them permanently.

Comment: @tadman thanks i have edited, i was only set up example for conceptual purpose

Comment: That's a step up with `mysqli`, but don't forget to use  [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) rather than the super clunky, potentially dangerously error prone method with manual escaping and string interpolation. There's a lot of recommendations in [PHP the Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) that are worth reading and following.

Comment: I get the issue with code injection.  It just isn't a big deal in this application for reasons that I will not go into.  I still need an answer to the original question:  why does the same data for a trademark symbol (ampersand hashtag 153 semi-colon) save correctly in a varchar field and get converted to unicode in a text field?  The database uses Latin1 compilation and both fields are saved in the same update statement.